# What does Nu (ν) prefix mean?

Tags: mosfet, units

Stumbled upon this in [ZVN4525E6](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZVN4525E6.pdf) datasheet:

Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current (IDSS): 35 νA @ VDS = 250V, VGS = 0V

The letter is [U+03BD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(letter)) and it is not in any common [unit prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix) that I know.

My guess this is either substitute for "nano" (since capital Nu is "N"), or some weird expression of current via power (as in V*A). Both make little sense to me.

Also, while I am here asking anyway, is this FET a good choice for low side switching of small loads in 24V system controlled by 3.3V logic *but also compatible with 24V pull-ups*? This was actually the only choice left in parametric search after I selected 30V VDS&VGS and 3V threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo of some sort. The Greek letter nu (looks like an italic 'v') is not an SI prefix, but may have been mistakenly used instead of an 'n' (nano). There are other 'n' and 'μ' prefixes in the datasheet, so it is not clear why they are not typed in. Comparing to a similar device (ZVN4525Z), you can see that nA is the correct unit.
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZVN4525Z.pdf

Comment: Oh, yeah.. good catch on similar datasheet. Although I have no idea how anybody can mistake one for the other, unless they are next to each other on some weird keyboard layout

Comment: @Maple it's actually an easy mistake to make, thanks to the the Symbol font, used in MS Word and elsewhere. It replaces Roman letters with their closest Greek equivalents. So to write microamps the correct thing to do is type "mA", then select the "m" and switch it to the Symbol font to get "µA". Here, either somebody had a brain-cramp and switched the font on the first character of "nA" even though it wasn't needed, or maybe they were attempting to correct "µA" to "nA" and forgot to switch the first character away from the Symbol font.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub Nice theory, but it's an actual 'ν' and not a 'n' in a different font. Besides, I really really hope that nobody uses these weird font-substitutions any more in 2015. Unicode is around much longer...

Comment: @asdfex True enough. Okay here's an alternate theory ;-), and a more plausible one at that. In Mathcad the correct way to type a Greek letter is to type the closest Roman letter and then hit [Ctrl+G] to switch it to Greek. So maybe the datasheet was written in Mathcad (or something similar) and this was an accidental [Ctrl+G].